# My Kentico version 7 to version 8 upgrade script is still executing after 72 hours. Is this typical?

Tags: sql-server, version, upgrade, kentico

We're following the Kentico guidelines for upgrading  our CMS from version 7 to 9 by way of Version 8 and 8.1 in hops.

72 hours ago the upgrade script was initiated. It's still executing at a steady state (13% CPU of 8 CPU cores, 32 GB RAM). the Kentico SQL DB is 32GB

This seems excessive to me. However there's no reporting/indication as to progress or time to complete.

Do I pull the plug and investigate an underlying cause or simply let it carry on?

Comment: Which part of the process is still running, executing the script? Running the site after the upgrade or what?

Comment: Still running the script - > 75 hours now.

Comment: I'm willing to bet the process just froze up.  Check SSMS and find out which queries are running.  Honestly, of the hundred or so upgrades I've done, I've never had one run over 10 minutes.  Stop the process, restore the code and database and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In upgrade from v7 to v8 macros are resigned. Depending on number of objects(pages, contacts etc.) this can take very long time as each DB field is evaluated for macro existence and if it is found, macro signature is updated.

At this time, you might be closing to finish so it depends on state of the upgrade. But if you want, you can set up v7 backups, go with manual upgrade (SQL script, manual file change) and used tweaked upgrade procedure class. This is last part of upgrade executed at first request to application. You can find the procedure at:

https://gist.github.com/ondrejsevcik/d580d237c42bce2ddd9d